# FloatingAction default behavior doesn't work

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button, android-snackbar

I'm creating an app with a navigation drawer. And over all my fragments there needs to be a Floating Action button. But when I create a Snackbar the floatingactionbutton goes up, but never goes back down.

I don't know what I have done wrong.

My CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".layout.MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/add"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to your `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Nowp, that does not work either